# Remove duplicate values from Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach-loop-container

I can not "remove" the double values ​​from an array even if I use the function array_unique!

```
<?php
    $tags_array = array() ; 
    $query_tags = $mysql->Query("SELECT words AS kw FROM users ") ;
    /****
    *
    * This query return something like Array([1] => PHP,ASP,NET [2] => Ruby,Jquery,php,asp_net [3] => Php,asp,visualbasic,c# [4] => [5] =>)
    *
    *****/
    while($fetch_tags = $mysql->Fetch($query_tags)) 
    {
        foreach(explode(',',$fetch_tags['kw']) as $kw => $value) 
        {
            if(empty($value)) ;
            else 
            {
                $value = ucwords(strtolower($value)) ;
                $tags_array[] = $value ;
            } 
        }
    }
$tags_array = array_values(array_unique($tags_array, SORT_STRING)) ; 
print_r($tags_array) ;
/******
*
* print_r show somethings like this Array([1] => Asp [2] => Php [3] => Php [4] => Ruby [5] => Jquery [6] => Php [7] => Asp_net [8] = >C# [9] => Asp) 
*
* IT'S ONLY AN EXAMPLE TO SHOW YOU THE SITUATION 
*****/
?>
```

Comment: Sorry i'm little noob tell me who i can do it :( apologize me

Comment: Maybe there is some whitespace involved?  E.g., `"PHP, Ruby", "Asp, PHP" -> array("PHP", " Ruby", "Asp", " PHP")`.

Comment: I mean `$value = ucwords(strtolower(trim($value)));`. If the values have white spaces at the beginning or at the end, they won't be equal...

Comment: yes there is some whitespace ! damn i'm very stupid TNX Felix AND Ferdinand !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the returned values are in fact not unique. For example

```
$foo = array("PHP","php","pHP","PHP ");
$foo = array_unique($foo);
```

Will still contain 4 entries.

If any entries contain spaces you should `trim` these.

Comment: This is why he normalizes those with `ucwords(strtolower($value))`?

Comment: @Ferdinand. The 4th entry has a space which will be missed by that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use values as keys, they can only exist once and you don't have any numbers as your keywords (hopefully):

```
$tags_array = array_keys(array_flip(($tags_array));
```

`array_flip` will use values as keys (and drop duplicate values) and `array_keys` will then return all keys as values again.

Comment: Why should he use `array_keys(array_flip(...))` instead of just using `array_unique()`?

Comment: I agree with Ferdinand, seems convoluted at best, and breaks when the values aren't scalars.

Comment: @Wrikken: In the question the values all are strings, no numeric parts given.

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer: As an example to show that array_unique does work.

Comment: @hakre: yes, in this question they are. However, people look at the answers here online more then they ask, and others may have non-scalars in their arrays. Suggesting a possibly broken solution for them (granted, in this scenario it will work although it didn't solve the real problem) while there is a proper tool in the question (namely `array_unique`) will not serve them well. I mainly commented for their sake, outlining when and where this solution is not valid. Your solution isn't wrong, or I would've downvoted, it's just not the proper tool.

Answer (score 0):

Given that is the only thing that aray_unique is supposed to do, I find it very surprising it's not doing it. What is apparent from your post, is that maybe you think 'php' is the same thing as 'PHP'?

When I try the following I get unique results:

```
$d=Array('PHP,ASP,NET','Ruby,Jquery,php,asp_net','Php,asp,visualbasic,c#');

$o=array();

foreach ($d as $i) {
    $p=explode(',',$i);
    foreach ($p as $q) {
      $o[]=strtoupper($q);
    }
}
print_r(array_unique($o));
```

However the issue only arises because your database schema is not normalised.

Answer (score 0):

As no one seemed to have provided the right answer, I'll repeat my comment here:

It might be that the words have preceding or trailing white spaces. Then they will never be equal to each other. You can remove these white spaces with [`trim` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
$value = ucwords(strtolower(trim($value)));
```